# Should a non-powered USB hub be able to connect two wireless devices?

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I recently got a non-powered USB hub that connects a wireless mouse and keyboard via two separate dongles. However, they never work when I first connect the hub to my laptop or desktop, which both run Windows. Even if I have the hub already plugged into the laptop/desktop when I turn whichever on, the devices don't work.

The only way to get either mouse or keyboard to work is to unplug the dongle then re-plug it back in. Basically, the hub is useless at the moment since I have to unplug and reconnect each dongle anyways.

So would a powered USB hub avoid this issue? I'm not sure how hubs exactly work so I want to just save myself the trip and purchase of a powered hub if it won't help.

Answer (score 0):

You actually answered your own question "The only way to get either mouse or keyboard to work is to unplug the dongle then re-plug it back in. Basically, the hub is useless at the moment since I have to unplug and reconnect each dongle anyways." shows a non powered hub can power your wireless devices.

The issue is likely to be driver and/or power saving/power state related - ie its a software problem.

Comment: Hmm that's what I suspected as well, especially since I do see popups related to the devices' drivers going wonky when I unplug and replug the dongles. Would getting a powered hub not resolve this issue?

Comment: Getting an identical powered hub won't likely help.  I am speculating here but I posit  if you get a hub with a different chipset that plays better with Windows drivers this may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the standard USB 2.0 devices are only allowed to draw 100 mA of power (@5v = 500 mW), and therefore, they can only redistribute less than 100 mA of power.  A typical 802.11 radio requires about 900 mW (180 mA) of power so you are exceeding the power-draw if you can get one to work (the USB hub is already drawing more power and sending it to the transceiver than the standard requires).  A bluetooth adapter (often used by keyboards & mouses) typically uses 300mW (60 mA) each, so you have enough power for one of them, but not necessarily enough for two.

Also, the way most of these devices work is they have a pre-amp and the power level can be changed within the pre-amp, but then it goes through a massive, fixed-gain (like 1000x), power-amp, which draws about 95% of the power, is always active, and cannot be changed in any way to save power.

You can buy a powered USB 2.0 hub (not labeled "lowpower" - it is required to supply at least 5 x 100 mA to each port ~ https://www.manualslib.com/manual/576944/Samsung-Spinpoint-M9tu.html?page=44) or just get a powered USB 3.0 hub with normal USB ports (these produce a minimum of 4.5w = 900 mA).

Comment: If this were the case, why would it work after the dongles are removed and plugged back in again?  Also, why would these dongles draw significant power?  They are receivers, not transmitters, In fact, according to https://www.tomsguide.com/us/squeezing-more-life-out-of-your-notebook,review-583-12.html these transmitters typically draw less then 15ma each.

Comment: Also, looking at Bluetooth, Bluetooth class 2 devices (range 10 meters - typical for a Bluetooth keyboard) have a maximum power output of 2.4mw.  Even Class 1 devices have a maximum power output of 100mW.  https://www.rfwireless-world.com/Tutorials/Bluetooth-power-classes.html